# git で subtree strategy でのマージの挙動は？

Tags: git, アルゴリズム

`git merge -s subtree` とすると、 subtree の strategy でマージを行うことができます。このときのマージを計算するアルゴリズムの挙動が、いまいちわかっていないです。

疑似コードぐらいの粒度で、このマージアルゴリズムの挙動を説明すると、どのようなものになりますか？